# AWS Lambda - Error: Cannot find module 'uuid/v4'

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, uuid

I am receiving this Error when trying to use UUID Module in AWS Lambda JavaScript code.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'uuid/v4'
```

I am not using AWSCLI or NPM, i am instead using the AWS Lambda dashboard to author the Lambda Functions in JavaScript.

```html
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const AWSUUID = require('uuid/v4');
const AWSGamelift = new AWS.GameLift();

exports.handler = async (event) => 
{
 //...
```

Ive been searching Google nonstop trying to find a way to get the UUID Module to work. I do not want to have to setup and use an NPM environment.

Is there some method on the AWS Lambda dashboard to provide access to the UUID Module for Lambda code?

Comment: Maybe there is a lambda layer for that? One layer repository is [here](https://github.com/mthenw/awesome-layers). Can look for others (or create your own) if non of the layers there contains uuid.

Comment: Alternatively, if the uuid library is 'small' you could just bundle it with your code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to install `uuid` package. `uuid` recently did a [breaking change](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#deep-requires-now-deprecated), the way you use it. New way is

```
const {"v4": uuidv4} = require('uuid');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore and I get an error saying: `Error: Cannot find module 'uuid'`, is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 4):

Now available as part of the default Nodejs Lambda, you can use crypto:

`import { randomUUID } from "crypto";`

Usage:
`console.log("randomUUID: " + randomUUID());`

Now with a demo: https://youtu.be/ciNxeatqAXk

Comment: Best way to do instead of using uuid library as it reduces your bundle, improving performance of lambda code

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda Layers is an option for this if we don't want to setup any npm environment.

Create a new Layer for your from Lambda function from the AWS console and upload the zip file of the `node_modules` directory containing uuid npm package.

Few things to remember to make this work:

1. The directory structure has to be maintained as per AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path

[image]

This is important otherwise Lambda function wont recognise the packages.

2. Your Lambda function's IAM role has to have `lambda:GetLayerVersion` action permission else missing package issue will arise. This is again clearly explained in the documentation mentioned above.

Once these are done, you can execute your code. Sample response

[image]

nodejs folder structure is as follows

[image]

Comment: I gave this a go but it doesnt seem to have worked.

Comment: Could you show me the structure of your package.zip? I downloaded UUID package from Github and placed it into a .ZIP as such.

uuid-sdk.zip
nodejs/node_modules/uuid

Comment: Please place package.json as well in your zip file. package.json would just contain uuid as a dependent package and is under nodejs folder.

nodejs folder would contain package.json node_modules folder which inturn will contain uuid package

Comment: @mattyman174 i have added the screenshot of nodejs folder structure that worked for me in the original answer. Please give it a try.

Comment: This change does not seem to have helped. I will verify that the Permissions have been set correctly just to make sure. Im just amazed that UUID is not already available, since AWS use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

navigate to that file, and look around line number 3 in node_modules/expo-constants/exponentConstants.web.js

```
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4
```

and change it to:

```
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';
```

This error happens because of the file structure in node_modules/uuid, if you look there is no longer a uuidv4 to import and instead they export a v4. You could change all the places where the developers wrote uuidv4 to v4 but using the { this as that } syntax you don't have to rewrite a bunch of code.

Answer (score 0):

I use the full path and it works because my file is out of node_module folder:

```
const uuidv4 = require('./chat-server/node_modules/uuid').v4;
```

Answer (score 0):

In mycase I need to just import uuid as it is getting used by some graphql packages.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to all `Lamba Unhandled` and `Cannot find module 'uuid/v4'` errors.
Including the one from the question asker.

First, lambda errors arise with unavailability of modules in `amplify/backend/function/function_name/src/package.json` file.

Taking a look at my code below, I have excluded the `uuid` module in this `package.json` file, hence the error:

> Cannot find module '`uuid/v4`'

```js
{
  "name": "createorder",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",

  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.92"
  }
}
```

I got rid of the error after including the module in the `package.json` file.

After that, I ran the command `npm install` on `src` folder in: `amplify/backend/function/function_name/src`

This is the new code I ended up with:

```js
{
  "name": "createorder",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "uuid": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.92"
  }
}
```

Thanks! :)